# I don't have a student pilot certificate number yet, can I still take the checkride?

Tags: checkride

Around May 25th, my instructor signed the [IACRA](https://iacra.faa.gov/IACRA/Default.aspx) for my student pilot certificate application, and I printed the (paper) temporary certificate. However, where it should list the a certificate number, it only says “PENDING”.

My hours are completed, and I am pretty much checkride ready.  But when filling out the online version of [Form 8710](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/form/faa_8710-1.pdf), I am required to enter the number of my student pilot certificate.

We had a DPE lined up for this week, my all other requirements are completed. How do I complete the application without a certificate number?

Comment: You should probably ask the DPE you are scheduled with.  The temporary private pilot certificate they will issue when you pass will trump any student certificate, but you wouldn't want them to be surprised...

Comment: I think the answer is to put “PENDING” as the cert number, but I have no source. Your DPE has probably run into this before and should be able to confirm authoritatively.

Comment: The current processing date is June 4, fwiw.

Comment: My first question for you is how the hell did your current instructor solo you or allow you to accomplish your solo CC flights without a student pilot certificate?

Comment: Yes sir, I do have a student pilot certificate already, the issue is there has been no number assigned to it as of date (in the student pilot cert number it says "pending"), hence I was unsure how to proceed with the ppl application. The DPE instructed me to just put pending for now.

Comment: @CarloFelicione I’ve improved the clarity of what OP was asking.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, you need to discuss this with the CFI who signed your recommendation for the check ride as well as the DPE **before the check**. Likely there will be a solution, but without a Student Pilot Certificate (with a number) in your possession when you arrive for the check you, and your recommending CFI, may be in for a disappointment.

This is a link to a short [FAA document regarding Student Pilot Certificates](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/become/student_cert/), containing information which may be helpful for both you and your recommending CFI.

Comment: Thank you sir! Solved the issue, just put down pending for now.

Answer (score 3):

According to MY DPE, the answer is to enter “PENDING" for my pilot certificate number in the IACRA application.